# I'm trying to write a program that adds random numbers 0-1000 to a text file

Tags: java

The user chooses the file name and the number of random numbers. As of now, the program only saves the last random number to the text file

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a filename:");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a positive Integer:");
    int number = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i<number;i++){
        Random rand= new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(1001);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter (filename, "UTF-8");
        writer.println(random);
        writer.close(); 
        System.out.println(random);
    }   
 }
```

Comment: There are a few lines you could write outside of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Create your objects outside of your loop to avoid this problem. Otherwise, you're creating new object at each iteration and overwrite the file created each time.

Also, you should close your stream once you're done with it.

---

### Solution

```
Random rand = new Random()
int random;
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter (filename, "UTF-8");

for (int i=0; i<number;i++){
    random = rand.nextInt(1001);
    writer.println(random);
    System.out.println(random);
}   
writer.close();
```

Comment: You forgot to assign `rand.nextInt(1001)` to `random`

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the PrintWriter outside of the loop, so you don't continuously overwrite the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a filename:");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a positive Integer:");
    int number = scan.nextInt();

    Random rand= new Random();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter (filename, "UTF-8");
    for (int i=0; i<number;i++){
        int random = rand.nextInt(1001);
        writer.println(random);
        System.out.println(random);
    }
    writer.close(); 
}
```